# error opening an application in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

When I tried to open the application here.

http://amazedsaint.net/nerddinner

It gives me an error saying that:

> This application was created for an
>   expired beta release of Silverlight.
>   Please contact the owner of this
>   application and have them upgrade
>   their application using an official
>   release of Silverlight.

So what does this mean?

Comment: Seems self-explanatory to me.  What part is confusing you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's mean developer uses expired library of SilverLight to develop that application. This problem came from SilverLight 4 beta library. You can install this runtime http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bf5ab940-c011-4bd1-ad98-da671e491009&displaylang=en or wait for them upgrade library.